# Windows Command-Line Utilities Started Prompting for Password

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line-interface, credentials

Recently my computer started prompting for the password of my domain account (that I am logged on as) when running command-line tools such as tasklist or taskkill on remote domain computers. On other domain workstations, it does not ask for a password when running these utilities. For example:

```
taskkill /s DomainComputer1 /im process.exe /f
```

What policy or setting might have changed to do this? I know these are probably not related, but I checked settings related to UAC, Firewall, and Credential Manager--to no avail.

Comment: Perhaps check with your System Admin on if any changes were made.

Comment: @Cheekaleak I'm one of them. I'm thinking of resetting the computer account tomorrow. Maybe the secure channel is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the issue was caused by the secure session between the computer and domain becoming out of sync. The solution I used was to reset the computer account in Active Directory, then join the computer back to the domain.

I noticed NETLOGON errors in the System Events that explained the following:

> This computer was not able to set up a secure session with a domain controller in domain
>
> ADDITIONAL INFO
> If this computer is a domain controller for the specified domain, it sets up the secure session to the primary domain controller emulator in the specified domain. Otherwise, this computer sets up the secure session to any domain controller in the specified domain.